# F Distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

I can't figure out how to plot the F distribution in R, given two degrees of freedom using standard normal variates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at '?df' and '?curve'

Comment: methinks this is potential candidate for "homework" tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use `curve()`

```
curve(df(x, df1=1, df2=2), from=0, to=5)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/curve.html) of `curve()`

Answer (score 1):

`df` is the density of the F distribution. This can be found in `?distributions` and follows the standard naming conventions `dnorm` for normal distribution, `dt` for t distribution, etc. The [F distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution)  has two degrees of freedom parameters. Use `pf` if you want the CDF.

```
x = seq(0, 5, length = 100)
plot(x, df(x = x, df1 = 1, df2 = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, all! I figured it out with your comments.